# YQL or Yahoo Boss related web searches/keywords

Tags: yql

Does anyone know if Yahoo Boss or YQL can return related keywords for search ? 
Example I query for windows and I need results like : microsoft, glass, windows 7, XP, house, etc . ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `microsoft.bing.relatedsearch` table, which uses the RelatedSearch SourceType from the Bing API (2.0).

```
set appid='B57D2A9074308394D44BE2C16455F536E3A7CEB5' on microsoft.bing.relatedsearch;
select * from microsoft.bing.relatedsearch where query="windows"
```

<sup>([Try this in the YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=set%20appid%3D%27B57D2A9074308394D44BE2C16455F536E3A7CEB5%27%20on%20microsoft.bing.relatedsearch%3B%20select%20%2a%20from%20microsoft.bing.relatedsearch%20where%20query%3D%22windows%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys))</sup>

This query gives the following related keywords (blame Bing if you don't think they're good results!).

> Windows Live, Windows Update, Windows Downloads, Window 7 Wallpaper, Windows Live Messenger, Windows Internet Explorer, Windows XP Update Downloads, Bay Windows